# Unable to get the GoogleMap object

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have created a MapFragment class. Here I have created GoogleMap object by `googleMap = mMapView.getMap()` I have have a method **ParserTask** If I call **ParserTask** from onCreate of this method then **ParserTask** works succesfully and  `googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions)`works. But If I call method **ParserTask** from another Activity then `googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions)` does not work, it shows null pointer exception. I think here *googleMap* does not get the instance of MapView. Now can anyone please give me a suggestion so that I can get the instance of *googleMap* in **ParserTask** If it is called from another activity. I have attached my code below:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener{

    MapView mMapView;

    private static final int MAP_ZOOM_AMOUNT=17;
    private TextView locName;
    private TextView mapIndicator;
    private GoogleMap googleMap=null;
    private String locationName;
    private String mapIndicatorText;
    private int categoryId;
    private int locationNameId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
                false);
        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        locName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_location_name);
        mapIndicator = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_map_indicator);
        locName.setText(locationName);
        mapIndicator.setText(Html.fromHtml("সব " + mapIndicatorText + " এর স্থান ম্যাপ এ দেখানো হয়েছে"));
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        LatLng loc = marker.getPosition();

    }


    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                RouteActivity parser = new RouteActivity();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {

            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }
            //setUpMapIfNeeded();
            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            ***googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);***

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the code look like in the other activity where you execute the ParserTask? Do you call it from the other activity before the fragment comes into view?

Comment: Yes I have called it before comes into view. I have called the parsarTask by    `MapFragment mapFragment=new MapFragment();
                mapFragment.parsarTask(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in the comments that you are running the `ParserTask` as follows:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
mapFragment.parserTask(result);
```

The issue with this is that the `MapView` is initialized when the `MapFragment`'s `onCreateView` is run, which is called when the `Fragment` comes into view. So the `MapView` hasn't been initialized when you try to run the `ParserTask`. Your options here are to reogranize your class structure (probably the better solution but also more work), or you could try this:

First make a class-level `PolylineOptions polylineOptions;` variable. Within your `onPostExecute()`, replace `googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);` with

```
if (googleMap != null) {
    googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
} else {
    polylineOptions = lineOptions;
}
```

and in your `onCreateView`, you could write:

```
if (polylineOptions != null) {
    googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```

The idea is that if the async task completes before the view is rendered, you save the data for when the view renders, and if the view renders before the async task completes, you immediately apply the effect.

Comment: Is there any way we can save the  `GoogleMap` object and use wheather we need?

Comment: What is class-level variable?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html
ie, your `locationNameId`, `categoryId` are both class variables. And I don't really understand your first question

Comment: In first question I asked if I can hold the value of a variable if it is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use AsyncTask. Instead I used a handler and a thread.

You can remove the part of the AsyncTask and try my code.

```
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    googleMap.addMarker(marker1);
                    googleMap.addMarker(marker2);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng1, zoom));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng2, zoom));
                    polylineOptions.addAll(points);
                    polylineOptions.width(10);
                    polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
                    googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                    //disable the rotation, scroll of the map
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

                }
            });
        }
    };

    mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```